# Customising Symfony2 CollectionType Form field display

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, tags

I've been experimenting with Symfony forms for some time. Without a doubt Symfony's FormType is a great feature which help create robust forms, especially with related entities (eg. ManyToMany, OneToMany etc.). The FormType makes my job a lot less complicated and easy when it comes to persistence. One of these case is the embedded forms, where u have multiple(lets say `Category` and `Tag`) entities with ManyToMany relation. Using FormType, I can create a 'Select dropdown' field using ChoiceType form field to choose category from, embed another CollectionType field with multiple 'text input' fields to accept multiple `tagname`, and finally a submit button. All I need is to add the `cascade = {persist}` option using annotations on the `categoryname` property of the `Category` entity and Wallah!

Now what if I wanted to create a single input field which can accept multiple tags, instead of having multiple input fields. Like this:

[image]

To do this I can create an `<input>` element using CollectionType form field, and then in my html.twig I can insert the javascript(jquery/AngularJS) dependency as attributes.

This can be done by using jquery Chosen or Select2 https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-select-box-components-chosen-vs-select2/

or by using AngularJS ngTagsInput component http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

*Not just this particular case, I know that jquery delivers almost everything u want to do on the client side, and works good with Symfony, but I've been looking into AngularJS for some time now and it is undoubtedly true that it is further a step ahead of jquery or any other javascript framework. Thus my opinion is a little biased towards AngularJS.*

The thing is, jquery(Chosen/Select2) uses `<select>` element and the AngularJS(ngTagsInput) uses custom `<tags-input>` element to display this field. Although with AngularJS I can make some elementary changes and convert the `<tags-input>` element to `<div ngTagsInput>` but I can't convert it to **`<input ngTagsInput>`** because the standard HTML`<input>` element has no closing tag, thus many features like `auto-complete` don't work. [Customizing ngTagsInput & autoComplete directives (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371035/customizing-ngtagsinput-autocomplete-directives-angularjs/38383917#38383917)

**Problem:** For Symfony to persist the CollectionType field input in the standard way I need to use the `<input>` element to display the field.

**Questions:**

1. How do I make this work?
2. How compatible are Symfony and AngularJS? And is it recommended to use them together?

All help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree that the Form component is awesome but it does want to take over much of the html form elements.  I gave up on the Form component when I moved to using React on the client.

Comment: @Cerad So in your opinion I should try creating the form entirely in AngularJS itself?

Comment: Correct.  But it is strictly my opinion.  Developers much smarter than me may have figured out a better way.  Hopefully, some of them will respond.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks a lot for your input

Comment: @Cerad One question though, if I do create the form in Angular, how would I persist the data manually? I've tried with the ManyToMany `Category` `Tag` example, but the tags just do not get added to the category. Can you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306116/symfony2-manytomany-bidirectional-relationship-how-to-persist-manually

Comment: Not going to be much help here either.  I gave up using the Doctrine ORM mostly because there was too much magic going on under the hood for me.  Easier for me to just write a bit of code and persist things that way I need them.  But yes, you do need a cascade="persist" on your relations to get child entities to automatically persist.

Comment: @Ceard I hear you.. Doctrine, as much as it helps it handicaps u as well.. guess I gotta get back to basics. Thanks again